# MS Access no tiene font San Serif

Tags: ms-access, fuentes

Estoy haciendo un informe muy ancho, ya configuré la hoja en landscape y utilizé letra Arial Narrow para los campos, pero aún hay un campo que no entra en la hoja. Es imperativo que el informe completo entre en una hoja.
Investigando letras más estrechas que Arial Narrow me encontré con que San Serif es más estrecha, sin embargo en mi listado de fonts en Access no me aparece San Serif, a pesar que si está en mi windows (traté de instalarlo y me dice que ya existe)

¿Alguien sabe como puedo "actualizar" los fonts en Access, si es que eso tiene algún sentido?

Comment: Cambia el tamaño de la fuente a 8 o 9px y te ahorras búsquedas y cambios de configuraciones

Answer (score 0):

Creo que te estás confudiendo. No existe una fuente Sans Serif como tal, por eso no la encuentras.

Sans Serif es una **tipografía de fuente**. Se caracteriza porque cada carácter carece de las pequeñas llamadas remates o serifas; lo que son unos adornos ubicados normalmente en los extremos de las líneas de los caracteres

[Sans Serif](https://www.creativosonline.org/blog/30-de-las-fuentes-mas-populares-sans-serif.html#Que_es_una_tipografia_Sans_Serif)

Tienes que buscar otra fuente diferente. Prueba Times New Roman, MS Serif, Calibri, Verdana, Helvetica... No son todas San Serif pero quizás te sirvan. Tendrás que probar hasta dar con ello.

Access se alimenta de las fuentes que tengas instaladas en Windows.

Por otro lado, en otras webs puedes encontrar recomendaciones:

[Las mejores tipografías Sans Serif](https://www.creativosonline.org/blog/30-de-las-fuentes-mas-populares-sans-serif.html#Las_mejores_tipografias_Sans_Serif)

Comment: muchas gracias, ha sido muy útil tu explicación

Answer (score 0):

Si buscas una tipografia mas angosta que Arial Narrow puedes probar alguna de estas fuentes de Google.

1. Ir a https://fonts.google.com/?width=1
2. Selecciona la que deseas. Por ejemplo ['Dorsa'](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Dorsa?width=1), y presiona 'Download family'
3. Al descargar el archivo `.zip`, lo descomprimes y buscas el archivo `.ttf` que viene incluido
4. Instala la fuente haciendo doble clic en el archivo.
5. Vuelve a abrir Access y tendras la nueva fuente disponible.

Comment: gracias, eso es perfecto

Comment: Resultó bien? cuentame si funcionó o si te queda alguna duda

Comment: si, muchas gracias, funcionó perfecto